# What are examples of non linear activation functions that are in the range of plus to minus infinity?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-layer, autoencoder, activation-function

I am training an auto encoder to reconstruct a TFIDF vectors whose elements can lie in the range of - infinity to + infinity. What apart from linear activation can I use as a possible non linear activation function on the auto encoder's output layer? The activation function is desired to give outputs in the + infinity to - infinity range.

All my other NN layers, including the 'Bottleneck' have tanh activation. I am using cosine_proximity loss and Adagrad optimization to guide gradient descent.

I am implementing the above in Keras with Tensorflow backend.

Comment: Why is the linear activation not enough?

Comment: ReLu? maybe -its consisted of 2 linear functions

Comment: @emsiiggy OP asks about a function with +/- inf in its image; plain ReLU's image is only non-negative reals. A leaky ReLU might fit the bill though.

Comment: Leaky ReLU was on my list. Finally settled with Elu though.